# how do I make a python program write directly to the command line?

Tags: 12.04, python, pygtk

This is the code I have, I want it so that I can write to the command-line from the window after I press the "SEND" button. If I want to see my "ifconfig" in the terminal, the command gets writen in the window and is displayed in the command line. All I want is for the window is to write to the command line after it is sent. I don't know if I should type \n and it will write a new line or if there is already a function for this built into pygtk.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
class Base:
    def send(self, widget):
        self.button.THIS_IS_WHERE_WRITE_IN_COMMANDLINE

    def writecommand(self, widget):
    self.textbox.get_text()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window = set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.window = set_size_request(600, 600)
        self.window.set_title("WINDOW")

        self.button = gtk.Button("SEND")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.send)
        self.textbox = gtk.Entry()
        self.textbox.connect("changed", self.writecommand)

        self.box1 = gtk.VBox()
        self.box1.pack_start(self.button)
        self.box1.pack_start(self.textbox)

        self.window.add(self.box1)
        self.window.show_all()
base = Base()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `system()` method in `os` package. Have rewritten the snippet, had a few corrections too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
import os
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
class Base:
    def send(self, widget):
        os.system('ifconfig') #this executes commands on the terminal

    def writecommand(self, widget):
        self.textbox.get_text()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        self.window.set_size_request(600, 600)
        self.window.set_title("WINDOW")

        self.button = gtk.Button("SEND")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.send)
        self.textbox = gtk.Entry()
        self.textbox.connect("changed", self.writecommand)

        self.box1 = gtk.VBox()
        self.box1.pack_start(self.button)
        self.box1.pack_start(self.textbox)

        self.window.add(self.box1)
        self.window.show_all()
base = Base()
gtk.main()
```

To find out more methods from the `os` package, in the python interpreter, type the following:

```
import os
dir(os)
```

which will list all methods. To get what those do, type

```
help(os.method_name)
```

for eg.

```
help(os.system)
```

Comment: great, i'll try it out in a few hours. where can I find more methods from the os package?

Comment: @user3368897: Check the edited answer.

Comment: @user3368897, OS module help https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#module-os or All module index https://docs.python.org/2/py-modindex.html . Also you can get all python doc for offline use, install `python-doc`